# GroupDocs.Compare result is working incorrectly

Tags: comparison, groupdocs

Comparison.Compare process Continues without error. `Errors count (1)` writes in `(ICompareResult)compareResult`. I think the error is caused by the license or products. The same process is working properly when I do on a single page. The second file given for comparison in the complex project returns as a result.

single page project `compareResult` return Comparison of source Path to targetPath
complex project `compareResult` return target Path

the used products:

```
GroupDocs.Viewer => **18.8.0.0**
GroupDocs.Comparison => **18.7.1.0**
<!-- language: c# -->
GroupDocs.Comparison.Common.ICompareResult compareResult = null;
GroupDocs.Comparison.Comparer comparer = new 
GroupDocs.Comparison.Comparer();
compareResult = comparer.Compare(sourcePath, targetPath, 
objComparisonSettings);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I reduced the level of comparison

Answer (score 0):

> I think the error is caused by the license or products

Please note that if you are evaluating the API in trial mode (without applying the license) you may face [limitations](https://docs.groupdocs.com/display/comparisonnet/Evaluation+Limitations+and+Licensing+of+GroupDocs.Comparison). Documents with more than 3 pages are not supported in trial mode.

However, you can request a temporary license [here](https://purchase.groupdocs.com/buy). Follow the wizard and on step 5 you can avail it.

Comment: I have a license. the red essay does not appear to be licensed. but when I do the viewer version 18.7.0 does not work at all.

Comment: how can I see the error in (ICompareResult)compareResult. Can you help me with this?

Comment: We are investigating this scenario. Your investigation ticket ID is COMPARISONNET-1773. We will inform you as we have any update or workaround available. I work with GroupDocs as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: We have an update for you. Currently getting error or exception details is not implemented in (ICompareResult)compareResult. API handles all the exceptions and do not throw them to the user. However, we could implement this in upcoming version 19.2. Where API will throw an exception to user instead of null result and user will be able to catch it using try-catch.
We will notify you as we have further updates.

Comment: Imagine that there is an "compare" variable generated from ICompareResult. "Error Count 1" is written in this variable. How can I see this error

Comment: You cannot see the error details in current version of the API. Because API doesn’t throw any exception/error. However, this will be fixed in 19.2. We’ll let you know when the release gets on-board.